# Where is the XC90 V8 2007 battery terminal?

Tags: volvo, xc90

Can someone tell me where the negative terminal of the battery under the hood of the Volvo XC90 year 2007 AWD V8 is?

Comment: The negative terminal of the battery will be on the battery, what do you really mean to ask?

Comment: @SolarMike: Under the hood, I can only find the battery terminal marked with "+" but no terminal that looks like the negative one.

Comment: Take a picture and show what you are looking at.

Comment: If you have found the (+) terminal then the OTHER terminal will be the (-) one.  Beyond that, please post a photo, perhaps you're not even looking at the battery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The battery in this vehicle is hidden and is not located under the hood. It is under a deck cover inside the rear of the vehicle.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTjenuS3l-w

The above YouTube video shows a couple methods to jump-start this vehicle, one using the positive terminal located under the hood, one using the rear battery location.

It is common and advised to use a frame member as the negative contact for a jump-start, after securing the positive connection to the battery, or in this case to the under-hood connection. *The use of a frame member is applicable to both the charging vehicle and the vehicle being charged.* When performing a jump-start, sparks can be expected and using a frame location for the last connection, away from the battery, minimizes the risk from exploding hydrogen released by the battery.

When using the under-hood connection, located at the end of the car opposite of the battery, the risk is obviously minimized, but the frame member remains as the negative connection.

If your objective is to disconnect the battery and is not to jump-start the car, open your tailgate and lift the panel covering the recessed storage area. The battery is located in the aft section of that area. Always remove the negative connection first, then the positive. Reverse the sequence (positive first) when re-connecting. If you've ever accidentally grounded the wrench on the positive terminal while working on a battery, you already know this tidbit of information.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I tried to jump start another car. According to some instruction, I need to connect the jump cable to the negative terminal of the Volvo battery that **provides** the jump power. Do I just connect the black clamp of the jump cable to the frame member exactly as when the Volvo is the receiver of the jump? Are arrangement of the two scenarios the same?

Comment: Yes, for the purposes of jump starting another vehicle, a metal component on the Volvo that is also part of the ground circuit will serve the required purpose. Heavier steel is a better choice than light sheet, in order to carry higher current. Prior to the 5 mph bumper requirement (USA), one could touch bumpers for the ground circuit, if they were metal.

Comment: I see. I would be great to add this point to the answer for completeness.

Comment: Added emphasis on request